# Change VisualState through Dependency Property (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a textbox inside a UserControl, I want to have two extra states for that textbox, Valid and Invalid. My code looks like this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="ExtendeTextBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationState">
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidState">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ValidState"></VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="HeaderText" Foreground="{ThemeResource ColorCompany}" ></TextBlock>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <Line  x:Name="BorderElement" Stroke="{ThemeResource ColorCompany}" X2="10000"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                      StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource TextBoxStrokeThickness}"   />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtbox"  Width="438" Height="56" Style="{StaticResource ExtendeTextBoxStyle}"
                 PlaceholderText="{x:Bind PlaceholderText, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

And in code-behind

```
  public bool HasError
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a dependency property that will indicate if there's an error. 
        /// This DP can be bound to a property of the VM.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HasError", typeof(bool), typeof(EditTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, HasErrorUpdated));

        // This method will update the Validation visual state which will be defined later in the Style
        private static void HasErrorUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            EditTextControl textBox = d as EditTextControl;

            Grid sds = textBox.Content as Grid;
            var mytxt = sds.Children.FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;

            if (textBox != null)
            {
                if (textBox.HasError)
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(mytxt, "InvalidState", false);
                else
                    VisualStateManager.GoToState(mytxt, "ValidState", false);
            }
        }
```

And I am calling this usercontrol inside my page like this

```
  <editors1:EditTextControl HasError="{x:Bind HasError, Mode=OneWay}"></editors1:EditTextControl>
```

On debugger, I can see that this line gets executed `VisualStateManager.GoToState(mytxt, "InvalidState", false);` But the visual state never changes and Red color never comes for that line. Can anyone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: Hi, I tested your code, it works fine (in my case it can be correctly turned into red), can you provide a minimal runnable demo? So that I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I have made a runnable demo. lines are supposed to come in red as HasError property is True, but its coming Green. https://tmpfiles.org/download/47485/App27.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, there is nothing wrong with your control itself, the problem lies in the assignment timing of the `HasError` variable in the `MainPage`:

Try this:

**Xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <editors1:EditTextControl HasError="{x:Bind HasError, Mode=OneWay}"
                              Loaded="EditTextControl_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasError;
    public bool HasError
    {
        get => _hasError;
        set
        {
            _hasError = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    private void EditTextControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HasError = true;
    }
}
```

First, `HasError` defaults to false when no value is assigned. You can manually change its value, but you need to notify the UI after the change. This requires the parent class inheriting the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and calling the `OnPropertyChanged` method when modifying the data.

Secondly, changing the value of `HasError` should be done when ensuring that the control has been loaded, otherwise although you have changed the value, but the control has not been loaded, this property change is invalid.

Thanks.