# VisualStateManager.GoToState not working for TextBox (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

I am trying to set VisualState of a TextBox through code.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtbox"  Width="438" Height="56" Style="{StaticResource ExtendeTextBoxStyle}"
             PlaceholderText="{x:Bind PlaceholderText, Mode=OneWay}" ></TextBox>
```

Codebehind

```
   private static void HasErrorUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         EditTextControl textBox = d as EditTextControl;
        Grid sds = textBox.Content as Grid;
        var mytxt = sds.Children.FirstOrDefault() as Control;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (textBox.HasError)
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(mytxt , "InvalidState", true);

            else
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(mytxt, "ValidState", false);
        }
    }
```

But this visual state never gets activated. What is wrong here?

Comment: check the return value of `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method. Does it return `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VisualStateManager.GoToState not working for TextBox (UWP)

Please check if `GoToState` has been called, if not, I suppose you have not implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface,  I viewed your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570182/change-visualstate-through-dependency-property-uwp). I found `HasError` is [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview), that means that you need bind it with property has implemented [`PropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) event handler.  When you call `OnPropertyChanged()` method, it will response `propertyChangedCallback` function.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
private bool _hasError;
public bool HasError
{
    get => _hasError;
    set
    {
        _hasError = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HasError = !HasError;
}
```